# Commonly Used Hidden Lists or Objects

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

What are few commonly used Hidden Lists and Objects that we should know of in Sharepoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://localhost"))
using (SPWeb web = site.RootWeb)
    foreach (SPList list in web.Lists)
        Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", list.Title ?? "(noname)", list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl);
```

I get:

```
Cache Profiles - /Cache Profiles
Content and Structure Reports - /Reports List
Converted Forms - /IWConvertedForms
Documents - /Documents
Form Templates - /FormServerTemplates
Images - /PublishingImages
List Template Gallery - /_catalogs/lt
Long Running Operation Status - /Long Running Operation Status
Master Page Gallery - /_catalogs/masterpage
Notification List - /Notification Pages
Pages - /Pages
Quick Deploy Items - /Quick Deploy Items
Relationships List - /Relationships List
Reusable Content - /ReusableContent
Site Collection Documents - /SiteCollectionDocuments
Site Collection Images - /SiteCollectionImages
Site Template Gallery - /_catalogs/wt
Style Library - /Style Library
User Information List - /_catalogs/users
Variation Labels - /Variation Labels
Web Part Gallery - /_catalogs/wp
Workflow Tasks - /WorkflowTasks
```

ps.: Publishing enabled, MOSS Enterprise

Comment: I asked this question when I came across History List while working with workflows. I dont see History List in this collection.

Comment: You can see Hidden lists in SharePoint designer, a History List is created when you create a workflow (my site has none). The code above shows actual System lists, like the Relationships List (variations referencial integrity)

Answer (score 0):

It may not be a terribly helpful answer, but my experience of Sharepoint development has indicated there are so many holes to fall down with the *non-hidden* and occasionally even documented lists and objects that wandering into the rocky territory of hidden ones is asking for trouble.

Comment: That is definitely true, but not knowing about hidden lists and objects, such as hidden fields associated with out-of-the-box content types when you are creating your own fields is definitely something that can cause problems, which I think is what this question is about.

Answer (score 0):

[Long Running Operations Status](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blogs/LKuhn/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=77) list.